# 4 of a kind on board ( texas holdem poker )

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules

If a board has four of a kind, let's say 9 9 9 9 J, how is the winner decided? Will kicker take part here?

Answer (score 1):

Players will have cards in hand. Remember that TH has the rule of picking the best 5 possible cards. This means that users holding the best of Q K A in their hands will win. Otherwise, they will tie by picking the community cards.

E.g.

```
9999J with two players holding 45 and 8T
```

They will tie because the best hand for them is 9999J in table.

Another example:

```
9999J with two players holding 4K 5J
```

The player holding 4K will win because their final hands will be 9999K and 9999J (the other J does not matter).

However the players here:

```
9999J with cards 4K QK
```

Or even:

```
9999J with cards 4K KK
```

will both tie with 9999K.

Yes, the answer is the kicker. If you have doubts, try always picking the best 5 cards for each player.